# How can I change slides with useState in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's probably a basic stuff, but I'm trying to figure out how can I change slides clicking on button. I have divs with data from movies API, so I'm clicking a button and I change slides, toggling active class in it. I can imagine doing it in plain javascript, but I'm trying to understand how can I do it in React.
The function looks like this:

```
 const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);
function changeSlide(){
      if(currentSlide <= few_movies.length){
          setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
      }else if(currentSlide >= few_movies.length){

      }
  }
```

So here, if currentSlide is less than length of movies array, I set the currentSlide to the next one. But I'm trying to figure out what could I do if currentSlide reaches an endpoint. I tried doing `setCurrentslide(0)` so it starts from the first slide again, but it doesn't really make sense.
Code for slide div:

```
<div className={`poster__item ${currentSlide===key ? 'active' : ''}`}</div>
```

Edit: So I added useInterval so it'd loop automatically through movives, but now it only changes back and forth between two first items without going further. Code looks like this:

```
useEffect(() =>{
        setInterval(() =>{
          if(currentSlide < few_movies.length - 1){
            setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
        }else(currentSlide >= few_movies.length){
          setCurrentSlide(0);
        }
        }, 2000)
  },[])
```

Comment: If you want it to loop then `setCurrentslide(0)` is just fine. Although the `currentSlide <= few_movies.length` should really be `currentSlide < few_movies.length - 1`, otherwise you will next set it to an out-of-bounds value. If you do not want it to loop, you will have to describe what you want to do.

Comment: I agree with @GabrielePetrioli, setCurrentslide(0) is just fine -- and in fact appropriate if the only action you are implementing is incrementing the slide, i.e., not allowing to go backward.  You'd need to implement some way of decrementing currentSlide if you want different behavior than a simple loop back to start.

Comment: I develop this slide https://sharp-knuth-880b64.netlify.app/ may be useful for you https://github.com/rcapdepaula/sitericardodepaula

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli i actually wanted to loop, so i made a setInterval() in useEffect() so it automatically loops through all movies and returns to the first one, but now it only changes between two first movies without going further, i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer YES you can make slides change using useState hook.

I suggest you hold all slides(movies) in an array or to have some indexed value for them like id, and then you can just make the math to change them based on the current slide index.
and on click event should increment or decrement the index if the current slide is for example 5 and you want to see prev slide you should just set the value of the state to current - 1. And that is basically the logic.

For returning ( displaying the slide ) You just watch which data from API have the same id (index) as the current slide, and just display its data.

Hope you could understand and I did not confuse you.
Good luck, happy codding.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code you posted, with the `setInterval` inside the `useEffect` id problematic because the `currentSlide` will never change inside it, since the `useEffect` has no dependencies. It will always remain at `0`, the initial value.

You can use `setTimeout` instead (*with the use of the dependency list of `useEffect`*), or you can use the function form which provides the current value and you return the new one.

so either

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    if (currentSlide < few_movies.length - 1) {
      setCurrentSlide(currentSlide + 1);
    } else {
      setCurrentSlide(0);
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, 2000);
}, [currentSlide])
```

or

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setCurrentSlide((currentSlideValue) => {
      if (currentSlide < few_movies.length - 1) {
        return currentSlide + 1;
      }
      return 0;
    })

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, 2000);
}, [])
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of setting it to `setCurrentslide(0)` why not just do nothing ?

same if they are at slide index `0` then don't let them go further down than `0`

```
currentSlide.length >= few_movies.length ? console.log('do nothing') : setCurrentSlide(oldState => oldState +1)
```